# Can't insert data into cell in qtablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I want to **`setItem()`** in **`qtablewidget`**
when i try to edit any cell in **`qtablewidget`**
I tried many functions but I cant to solve them.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(7)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(15)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(7, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(8, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(9, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(10, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(11, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(12, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(13, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(14, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


        def test():
            self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("test"))

        self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(test)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(7)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(8)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(9)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(10)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(11)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(12)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(13)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(14)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Column"))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Win  = Ui_MainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(Win)
Win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and I get this error:

**Error in sys.excepthook:**

**Original exception was:Unhandled Python exception**

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: look now to my code, please

Comment: Run the program in a prompt or terminal and you will see the full traceback, which is a recursion: `itemChanged` is called whenever **any** item is changed, and since in that function you're setting another item, you're causing the signal to call the function again. What are you trying to achieve? Also note that you're not expected to manually edit pyuic files, but only and always *import* them, as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems:

- Do not modify the classes generated by pyuic, they are a practical word. So for my solution you have to restore the .py by running: `python -m pyuic5 your_ui.ui -o mainwindow_ui.py -x`.
- The problem is that you are creating an infinite recursion. Say you start editing the item so the itemChanged signal will be emitted, when you add the new item itemChanged will also be emitted and this will insert another item which will cause itemChanged to be emitted, and so on ad infinitum causing your program to break. The solution is to prevent the signal from being emitted by inserting the item through `blockSignals` method.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from mainwindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.handle_item_changed)

    def handle_item_changed(self):
        self.ui.tableWidget.blockSignals(True)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("test"))
        self.ui.tableWidget.blockSignals(False)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win  = MainWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve it, you should make the cell not Null you should give the cell a value like an empty string

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).